# Disable and clear logs and remove event id 1102?

Tags: windows-7, windows, logging

Can I disable logs and remove event id 1102 (=log cleared event)?
I already tried:

```
Auditpol /set /category:* /success:disable
```

But that didn't work for audit successful event 1102!